# Custom counter printed correctly in situ, but not in nameref references

Tags: cross-referencing, counters, nameref

The journal that I'm submitting to has a LaTeX template (yay!), but the template suggests manually labeling supplemental figures. Since I'm too lazy to do that, I thought I would make a new counter and a new command that would keep track of it for me. However, in references to those supplemental figures, the counter shows up as 0.

As a minimal example,

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}

\newcounter{SFig}
\newcommand{\figsupp}[2]{\refstepcounter{SFig} \paragraph*{S\theSFig\ Fig.}\label{#1} {\bf #2}}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\section{Journal Article}
Lorem Ipsum  (\nameref{Supp:Supp1}).  Dolor sic amet (\nameref{Supp:Supp2}).

\section{Supplemental Information}
\figsupp{Supp:Supp1}{ I did some extra stuff}
\figsupp{Supp:Supp2} {I did even more extra stuff}

\end{document}
```

gives all 0s in the references, even though the output in the supplemental section is just fine.

[image: Supp figures numbered correctly in Supplement section, but not in the references in the text]

Comment: By the way: `\bf` is outdated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\label` is using the wrong information here -- I suggest to create the `\@currentlabel` and `\@currentlabelname` content directly and apply `\label` afterwards then.

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcounter{SFig}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\figsupp}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \refstepcounter{SFig}%
  \paragraph*{S\theSFig\ Fig.} {\bfseries{#2}}\phantomsection
  \protected@edef\@currentlabel{\theSFig}
  \protected@edef\@currentlabelname{S\theSFig\ Fig.}
  \label{#1}
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{Journal Article}
Lorem Ipsum  (\nameref{Supp:Supp1}).  Dolor sic amet (\nameref{Supp:Supp2}).

\clearpage
\section{Supplemental Information}
\figsupp{Supp:Supp1}{I did some extra stuff}
\figsupp{Supp:Supp2}{I did even more extra stuff}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Using `\protected@edef` caused the engine to crash for me, but just `\edef` worked.